# Дан массив символов. Указать те слова, которые содержат хотя бы одну букву k

Tags: c++

Моя идея. Разбиваю строку на слова до пробела, затем я проверяю полученную строку на содержание заданной буквы, если есть это буква в строке я вывожу строку. Вопрос в отладчике я смотрел у меня программа работает до 1-го nullptr и дальше прекращает работу, как мне поступить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

char *find_word(char *str, const char ch);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");

    char str[100] = "skate world sun take"; //набор слов.

    cout << str << endl;

    char *word = strtok(str, " "); //получаю новую строку

    while (*word) {
        cout << find_word(word, 'k') << ' ';
        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

//проверка на содержание буквы.
char *find_word(char *word, const char ch)
{
    char *start = word;
    while (*start) {
        if (*start == ch)
            return word;
        start++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: все что вы написали выше делается просто черз 'std::string sub = "k"; size_t pos1 = str.find(sub, 0);'

Comment: я меньше пол года изучаю с++ и до STL библиотек не дошёл

Comment: ну что поделать))) Бьярне научит)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас в программе полно логических ошибок. Чтобы разбираться дальше, нужно их устранить. Без этого ответ на ваш вопрос равносилен переписыванию кода.

1. Алгоритм, описанный Вами словами, неверный. После последнего слова нет пробела, значит вы его не найдёте. Кроме того, если идёт 2 пробела подряд и больше, алгоритм будет зря проверять пустые слова (хотя, это не ошибка).
2. Вы создали функцию, которая должна искать в слове букву, однако искать её она будет не в слове, а во всей фразе. Почему? Потому что strtok возвращает УКАЗАТЕЛЬ на то место, где начинается слово, а вы ищите букву k через этот указатель, то есть пробегаете фактически по массиву str до конца.
3. Цикл while вообще какой-то палёный. Зачем в нём искать ваше слово в пустой строке (NULL)? По идее, вам нужно переходить к следующей лексеме, а это делается совершенно не так. Условие выхода из цикла тоже неверное - нужно выходить по нулевому указателю, а не по нулевому символу.

Сначала нужно исправить эти ошибки, потом можно будет думать дальше.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, пойду разбираться

Comment: Как я понимаю указатель это часть строки???

Comment: Хм... если вы не владеете языком, то сначала следовало бы его изучить. Указатель - это (в данном случае) фактически АДРЕС позиции символа. Он лишь указывает на то место в вашем str, с которого начинается слово.

Comment: хочу уточнить по поводу 2-ого пункта. Может тогда проще будет создать временный массив, который будет хранить слово и потом его проверять на содержание символа.

Comment: Нет, не нужно. Просто я бы шёл спокойно по массиву str и в зависимости от встреченного символа выполнял бы ту или иную операцию. Если вижу пробел или конец строки - заканчивается слово, если вижу букву 'k', значит считаю текущее слово подходящим. Можно хранить указатель на начало слова и на его конец, тогда его легко будет вывести.

Comment: Спасибо за идею